# Add column in specific position of table. MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table AA which it's definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE `AA` (
   `a` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `b` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `c` int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY  (`a`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I would like to add a column to the table however I want this column to be between `b` and `c, If I would create the table now it would have been like:

```
CREATE TABLE `AA` (
   `a` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `b` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `ba` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `c` int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY  (`a`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The thing is that the table already  contains data so I can not drop and recreate it. When I use `alter table add column`  it adds the column to the end.

How do I insert a new column in specific position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `AFTER`.  See the [mysql `ALTER TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) syntax for more details

```
ALTER TABLE AA ADD COLUMN c int AFTER b
```

If you wanted to add it at the beginning you would use `FIRST`.

Answer (score 0):

Easy with **[alter table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)**

```
ALTER table table_name
    Add column columnName integer AFTER columnOtherName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE `AA` ADD `ba` INT NOT NULL AFTER `b`
```